# Conditionals in Handlebars.js when fetching data from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-sheets, handlebars.js

## Where I'm At

I'm using [Tabletop.js](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) and Handlebars.js to pull all the data from a Google Spreadsheet related to politician statements and then display them onto the page.

## Problem

**a)** I'm having trouble fetching the data for `validity` from the console from a specific object. When I console.log(data), I'm able to get each of the objects from the Google Spreadsheet, but I haven't been able to get just `validity` from the first or third object for instance.

### Console (single object)

```
Object {Facts: Tabletop.Model}
+-- Facts: Tabletop.Model
 ++-- column_names: Array[8]
 ++-- elements: Array[10]
   +++-- 0: Object
   +++-- citation1url: "Citation 1-1"
   +++-- citation2url: "Citation 2-1"
   +++-- citation3url: "Citation 3-1"
   +++-- datesaid: "2/20/2015"
   +++-- explanation: "Explanation 1"
   +++-- name: "Politician 1"
   +++-- rowNumber: 1
   +++-- statement: "This is my first statement"
   +++-- validity: "TRUE"
```

**b)** Having syntax issues, wondering if using conditionals in Handlebars would be most efficient way of changing the border color of an element if the `validity` of a statement (based off data from the spreadsheet) is true, false or unconfirmed **vs.** writing an if/statement and using jQuery's .css() or .addClass()?

### Trying to do something like this (both aren't working)

```
if (validity == true) {
     $(".container").css("border", "1px solid #2ECC40");
} else if (validity == unconfirmed) {
    $(".container").css("border", "1px solid #FFDC00");
} else (validity == false) {
    $(".container").css("border", "1px solid #FFDC00");
}
```

**OR**

```
{#if Facts.validity.TRUE }}
    <div class="trueContainer container">
{{else if Facts.validity.FALSE}}
    <div class="falseContainer container">
{{else Facts.validity.UNCONFIRMED}}
    <div class="falseContainer container">
{{/if}}
```

---

### Links

**Google Spreadsheet:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1glFIExkcuDvhyu5GPMaOesB2SlJNJrSPdBZQxxzMMc4/pubhtml

**JSBin:** http://jsbin.com/zomopeqoza/1/edit?html,css,output

### Relevant Files

#### scripts (Currently inline)

```
<!-- This is where the template for facts goes -->
<script id="poli" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="container">
    <p class="claim">Claim: {{name}} has said "{{statement}}"</p>
    <p class="explanation">This statement is {{validity}}. This is reason number one and a detailed explanation. <a href=""><sup class="unconfirmed">1</sup></a> This is reason number two with a detailed explanation. <a href=""><sup class="unconfirmed">2</sup></a> And this is {{explanation}} <a href=""><sup class="unconfirmed">3</sup></a> These fact checking boxes should always include 2-3 cited explanation, written by the reporter and linked to a file on DocumentCloud or Soundcloud.</p>
</div>
</script>

var public_spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1glFIExkcuDvhyu5GPMaOesB2SlJNJrSPdBZQxxzMMc4/pubhtml";

      $(document).ready( function() {
        Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
                         callback: showInfo,
                         parseNumbers: true } );
      });
      function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
        var source   = $("#poli").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        // The actual name of the sheet, not entire .csv
        $.each( tabletop.sheets("Facts").all(), function(i, fact) {
          var html = template(fact);

          // You need an element with this id or class in your HTML
          $("#poli-list").append(html);
          console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

#### style.css

```
/*----------------------------------
MAIN STYLES
----------------------------------*/

.trueContainer {
    border: 2px solid #2ECC40;
}

.falseContainer {
    border: 2px solid #FF4136;
}

.unconfirmedContainer {
    border: 2px solid #FFDC00;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding: 0.5%;
    width: 50%;
}

.claim, sup {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
}

sup {
    padding: 2px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;

}

.explanation {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 0.025px;
}

.true {
    color: #2ECC40;
}

.false {
    color: #FF4136
}

.unconfirmed {
    color: #FFDC00;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I got your question. To print validity you can console this `data.Facts.elements[i].validity` where i is 0 to length of elements

Comment: And for (b) you can append the validity value as class and have that class in CSS with respective border styles. Something like this `$('.container').eq(i).addClass(data.Facts.elements[i].validity);`

Comment: I'll try those out tonight